# Is it possible to use sp_addrolemember on a SQL Server database without Management Studio? Only using sqlcmd

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, windows-server

[image: SQL role membership]

I’m trying to avoid installing Management Studio on multiple servers.

Is it possible to add `Sp_addrolemember` to a database only using `sqlcmd`?

I tried:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E 

USE [DBName]

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DBName', 'db_owner';

go
```

But no luck.

`MSG 15151 level 16 State 1`

Comment: Might be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But you used the wrong syntax. Once connected to SQLCMD, the [correct Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) would be:

```
USE [DBName]

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'username';

GO
```

But you don't need to install Management Studio on the server to access the database, you can access the servers remotely from the Management Studio you have installed on your desktop.